# Installation of eclipse php in ubuntu

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, installation

How to install  **eclipse php in ubuntu** platform using **apt get install**. Any other utilities are required to do that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't! Don't use apt-get for Eclipse. Instead, follow these [steps](http://techmix.net/blog/2009/07/31/eclipse-35-galileo-on-ubuntu-jaunty-904/) to install it "manually".

Comment: Ops, I, and UBUNTU support,  say YES, USE IT! Is faster, and secure!  See my answer.  Another problem is that, for many people (beginners), JAVA.run file not runs, then, these 2009's steps are not "plug-and-play" like 2012's apt-get or Synaptic.

Comment: 2012: use aptitude install eclipse

Answer (score 17):

The simplest solution, which will allow you to have the latest version, would be to :

- go to http://eclipse.org/pdt/
- download the lastest version (icon on the right)
- Choose the "PDT 2.1 All In Ones / Eclipse PHP Package" package that's OK for you : Linux x86, 32 or 64 bits
- download that package
- unzip it
- and voila, you can run Eclipse PDT

Advantages :

- last version
- doesn't require root privileges

I'm always using this solution, because new versions of Eclipse PDT generally bring nice enhancements, and are not integrated on the Ubuntu repositories before a long time passes... And I've never had any problem with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are the SIMPLEST one for UBUNTU 10+ ... and I have problems with the other "handmade methods" answered here.

SEE https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPEclipse  or  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipsePDT

1. Use "software centre" or Synaptic to install Eclipse... or apt-get.
2. Run Eclipse and use the Help/Add to add the PHP-Eclipse (PDT) package.

(Pascal's answer says "Don't use apt-get" but I say) UBUNTU supports and I recommend: **USE IT, use `apt-get`**! Is faster, simple and secure!

PS: "PDT - PHP Development Tool" is the official name for "Eclipse-PHP".

---

DETAILED INSTALLATION

NOTE: On Ubuntu 10+ this method will install Eclipse 3.5+ (Galileo) and PDT 2.1+. If you have problems or want "lower risk to re-do", run, at the second step bellow, the Eclipse with root, 
     `$sudo eclipse`

1. Install Eclipse:  Open Synaptic Package Manager (System/Administration/Synaptic Package Manager), Find the package "eclipse" and mark it for installation, Click Apply.
2. Install PHP Development Tools (PDT): Open Eclipse (you must specify your workspace); ignore the "Welcome to Eclipse" screen is displayed, select menu Help/Install New Software...

   - The "Galileo" site must be added, click "Add..." and input:
   - *Name*: Galileo   *Location*: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/
   - Once this is available, select "Galileo" in the Work with: drop-down list.
   - Enter "php" into the filter text, two entries should be displayed for "PHP Developer Tools (PDT)"; one under Programming Languages, another under Web, XML, and Java EE Development. Select both and click "Next".
   - Verify that the items you wish to install are displayed on the "Install Details" screen and click "Finish".
   - Eclipse will need restarted for the update to complete.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct & Easy way : http://ubuntulinuxpower.blogspot.com/2013/01/installing-eclipse-pdt-with-php-support.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.