# Eclipse (on Ubuntu) do not have jsp, html and other web-files template

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-9.10

I installed Eclipse using Synaptic Package Manager (Ubuntu 9.10).
However, my Eclipse does not have any HTML template (in New dialog) or JSP template.
How can I fix it so that I will have some HTML and JSP templates overthere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch Eclipse plugin from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo and select Web Developments stuffs solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to install Eclipse from the ubuntu repository but to [install it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420989/installation-of-eclipse-php-in-ubuntu/1421011#1421011) instead (and grab [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php)). Just be **sure** to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816485/eclipse-galileo-click-problem-on-ubuntu-9-10/1816499#1816499) to fix the "click problem" due to a bug with Eclipse 3.5 and GTK+ 2.8.

**Update:** The reasons to prefer a manual install are explained in [EclipseIDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE). First, there is no guarantee to find the most recent of Eclipse in the repository (in Ubuntu 9.04, the packaged version of Eclipse was totally outdated). Second, even  if you find an up-to-date version (like for Ubuntu 9.10), you'll need to run Eclipse as root to install plugins not available in Package Manager - why did they start to package plugin, this is just crazy - which is not a good idea. User mode installation solves this problem.

Comment: Why not? What's about automatically upgrade?

Comment: Thanks. I've come through some of your links. I got the annoy unclickable button sometimes but I ignored them since I thought it's a bug of ubuntu. Downloading Eclipse right now...

Comment: Hmm, the work around you introduced is already included in the latest release of Eclipse on Ubuntu Repositories.

Comment: @Phuong This fix is needed if you decide to go for the user mode installation, it is indeed already applied in the packaged version.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `eclipse-wtp-webtools` package for static html files. I can't find one for jsp though.

Comment: For jsp, you can install it from the marketplace. Help -> Install New Software